# Add bundles, minifications and compressions over Azure CDN

Tags: c#, azure, compression, azure-cdn

I want to enable CDN for my web app in Azure. The app is a asp.net MVC project, in .NET Framework. I have some trouble because I find a lot of old versions explain how to implement Azure CDN.

I am following step by step these guides:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-add-to-web-app
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification#controlling-bundling-and-minification

I like this solution because does not use Azure Storages.

Here the step I am doing to obtain bundles, minifications and compressions.

For minification and bundling I am [enabling optimazion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification#controlling-bundling-and-minification) in the global.asax

For compression over CDN, [I have enabled compression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-improve-performance) but the default compression is gzip. I would prefere br over gzip instead. I am using **Azure CDN Standard from Microsoft**.

Two questions:

1. How can I use br compression over gzip?
2. How can I be sure I am using correctly CDN? I would expect to see the url of CDN for my js in the Developer tool of Chrome. But I see the url of my web site. However when I navigate the url of the CDN I correctly see a "copy" of the web site. But it is not a sufficient proof to me.

Any help please?

**EDIT**

Even if I disable compression in my cdn, I purge the cdn and then I wait 10 minutes I still receive a gzip as response.
When I disable the whole CDN I take control over web site again. I mean that my js are not compressed anymore.

**EDIT AGAIN**
If I navigate the CDN, I see this in the developer tool:
[image]

Comment: Azure CDN standard from Microsoft has br already configured. Depending on the client, compression algorithm is selected. If client supports both compression then br will be preferred. More information at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-improve-performance#compression-rules

Comment: @SadiqKhoja yes... the doc says that... but it seems something goes wrong... perhaps I am not the one I have same problem: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/33450